How to set the expire_in of a SAST artifact via a variable in .gitlab-ci.yml
I want to set the expire_in of the SAST artefact through a variable. The reason is, that the duration should differ in each environment.
For example, in dev -> 30 days. in stage -> never
variables:
  SAST_EXPIRE_IN: "30 days"

sast:
  stage: pre-build-tests
  artifacts:
    expire_in: $SAST_EXPIRE_IN
    paths:
      - gl-sast-report.json
    reports:
      sast: gl-sast-report.json

I'm getting the below error when the code is committed.
jobs:sast:artifacts expire in should be a duration
How can I fix this?

This might not be possible... There are open issues where this feature is requested, e.g. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/6412 or the epic https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/3589

Even though it does not seem to be possible to use variables for expire_in (see open gitlab issue) you could work around it by using two different jobs:
sast_stage:
  stage: pre-build-tests
  artifacts:
    expire_in: never
    paths:
      - gl-sast-report.json
    reports:
      sast: gl-sast-report.json
  rule:
    - if: '<Rule that only applies for stage>'

sast_dev:
  stage: pre-build-tests
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 30 days
    paths:
      - gl-sast-report.json
    reports:
      sast: gl-sast-report.json
  rule:
    - if: '<Rule that only applies for dev>'

By setting the rules you are able to execute the right job at the right time.

Yeah. I had to go with this solution.
